# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined Discord,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem, my code is showing

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined for pause command. All the other commands are working fine.

Reading Files.

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFIles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFIles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) {
        return;
    }
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(msg, args);
    } else if (command === 'userinfo') {
        client.commands.get('userinfo').execute(msg, args);
    } else if (command === 'delete') {
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return msg.reply('Enter a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
            return msg.reply('Enter a number between 1 and 99.');
        } else {
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                msg.channel.send('There was an error trying to delete messages');
            });
            msg.channel.send(`Deleted ${args} messages.`);
        }
    } else if (command === 'p' || command === 'play') {
        client.commands.get('play').execute(msg, args);
    } else if (command === 'pause') {
        client.commands.get('pause').execute(msg);
    }
});
```

pause.js code:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'pause',
    description: "Pause the current song.",
    execute(message){
       const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
       if(!queue) return message.reply("There is nothing playing").catch(console.error);
       if(queue.playing){
           queue.playing = false;
           queue.connection.dispatcher.pause(true);
           return queue.textChannel.send(`⏸ Paused.`).catch(console.error);
       }
    }
};
```

If I copy the code and paste the same code in `Client.on` it's working but it's showing error while using with `module.exports` .Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pause.js export - `execute` is not a property of the object. Try this:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'pause',
    description: "Pause the current song.",
    execute: function (message) {
       const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
       if(!queue) return message.reply("There is nothing playing").catch(console.error);
       if(queue.playing){
           queue.playing = false;
           queue.connection.dispatcher.pause(true);
           return queue.textChannel.send(`⏸ Paused.`).catch(console.error);
       }
    }
};
```

Create a property called `execute` and assign it's value the function that you have.

Comment: are you sure `.get('pause')` is returning anything?

Comment: I see my original post isn't actually the issue - the discord docs have that same syntax.

Comment: yes I am sure .get('pause') is returning correctly. It's just telling execute function within pause.js is undefined and I can't seem to get why because this syntax is working for all the other commands.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the `args` parameter to `execute()`?

Comment: This same syntax is working for some commands and showing error for some, and I cant seem to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the commands with this code:

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFIles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFIles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

So the command name is the file export .name. On your expore file, you have no name property. instead, you wrote title. Try this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'pause',
    description: "Pause the current song.",
    execute(message){
       const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
       if(!queue) return message.reply("There is nothing playing").catch(console.error);
       if(queue.playing){
           queue.playing = false;
           queue.connection.dispatcher.pause(true);
           return queue.textChannel.send(`⏸ Paused.`).catch(console.error);
       }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

so there you are set the command to execute by name but in your export there isn't name , which you are calling in the .get in event side , that why it return undefined , hope it's useful

Comment: `client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

 const commandFIles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
 
 for(const file of commandFIles){

    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);

}`

Comment: @Buazeez - Please don't post clarifying questions as answers. If the comment above is intended as your answer, please [edit] your answer and put your answer there (preferably with some explanation, not just one line of code.

Comment: @hrishitbiswas Also, if you have additional code to add to clarify your quesiton, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64197054/edit) your question and post it there, so that you can format it correctly as code.